# How to get last inserted native contact id in android

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I have to get distinct raw contact id using content resolver.

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                    null, null, null, null);

if (cur.getCount() > 0){                    
   while (cur.moveToNext()){                          
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));                         
        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

         System.out.println("id............"+id+"..."+name);                            
 }
}
```

Ist i have inserted all contacts into native contacts.Then Using above code i got all native contact id. How to get one id at a time after inserting 1 contact. Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you want last id or all id contact id..

Comment: i want last id not all contact  id..but using above code i got all id..please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Replace to

```
cursor.moveToLast();
```

you can easily get last id of the database